# Git merge says up to date but my files didn't change

Tags: git, git-merge

I have 2 branches, main and Android. Android branches has some plugins for android environment. I updated my android with main branch, git history shows changes but when I inspect files there is no changes. Even git diff shows my files is not same with android yet shows no changes on untracked list. How can I fix this?

When I try merging there was conflict and I ignored it. Discarded all changes on Android branch and try merging again. The problem occured when I do this. I think discarding all changes on Android branch when I try merging it caused all this problem.

I tried `git reset --hard Android` and `git checkout`. None of these worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you might have encountered a merge conflict when merging
the changes from the main branch into the Android branch, but you resolved it
by discarding all the changes on the Android branch. This can cause the merge to appear as "up to date" because Git thinks
there are no changes to merge, but in reality, you have lost the changes that were on the Android branch.
You can try creating a new branch from the main branch and cherry-picking
the commits that you want to apply to the Android branch:

```
- git checkout -b new-Android main 
- git cherry-pick <commit hash>
```

With cherry-pick, you can bring commit by commit into your branch, and with that, you can gradually resolve each code conflict manually.

Comment: Thank you. I was searching some commands like "cherry-pick".